# How to connect android device with appium using windows machine?

Tags: android, mobile, automation, appium, mobile-application

Could you please provide the step by step procedure to connect android device with appium in windows machine?

What are the the things we need to be installed to run android in the appium?
Please give clear details.Because I am new to this appium tool.

Following things I have followed from my-side:

```
1.Installed Java JDK-added environment variable
2.Installed appium
3.Installed eclipse without SDK(I don't know how to configure ADT,Android SDK)
4.Connected device and run the command window "adb devices"-It is showing connected device
5.When I run the appium "Play" button showing node js started but none of the emulator opened.
```

Could you please what are all the steps I have missed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this DOC, it has step by step instruction with screenshots link:[click](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0RYNvExsRQJZ0FYbVdjQmpKcVU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Document looks good.We are doing POC.So I need to know How I can start my first test with Appium.

When I click "Play" button in appium,it is thorwing error as 
_> warn: Appium support for versions of node < 0.12 has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please upgrade!
> error: No app set; either start appium with --app or pass in an 'app' value in desired capabilities, or set androidPackage to launch pre-existing app on device
> 
> 
> Node Server Process Ended_

Answer (score 1):

The emulator won't open unless you start a session. Clicking Play on Appium simply starts the Appium server. To start a session the simplest way, just click the inspector button (the magnifying glass).

Answer (score 0):

Install driver of your mobile phone. then in Appium Android Settings(click android icon), at Launch Device section, be sure that Launch AVD is **NOT** selected. Also, in Capabilities section select appropriate Platform settings

Comment: install your mobile device driver.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below mentioned link for detailed instructions for running appium on windows machine:
http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.1.0/?ruby#running-appium-on-windows

Comment: For the error:
No app set; either start appium with --app or pass in an 'app' value in desired capabilities, or set androidPackage to launch pre-existing app on device.  
You have to mention the application package name and the activity name you want to launch in the DesiredCapabilities.
Something like this:  
capabilites.setCapability("appPackage", "packageNameGoesHere");  
capabilites.setCapability("appActivity", "activityNameGoesHere");

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below mentioned posts:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/steps-configuring-appium-rakesh-kirola?trk=hp-feed-article-title-comment

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/appium-script-calculator-functionality-check-rakesh-kirola?trk=mp-author-card

Comment: Second LinkedIn url not working.Please correct it and thanks for your answer.